# Minimize and close button functionality change in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am developing a desktop application(cross platform) using 'codename one' for Windows(.exe) and MacOS(.dmg).
By default Desktop application will have minimize,maximize & close buttons.
i) Click on Minimize - It minimizes the app and will appear on task bar.
ii)Click on Maximize - It maximizes the app to fit the full screen size.
iii)Click on Close - App will close(It gets Terminated). 
If the user want to open again, they need to click on short cut icon.

My Requirement - Both minimize and maximize buttons should work same, but when user clicks on 'Close' button the app shouldn't get 'Terminated'(it should run in Background). 
Intended to develop 'Bitrix' Kind of application, After closing the App it should run in 'System tray' and user should be able to open it from System tray.

Could any one help me out to achieve this in 'Codenameone' as I got stuck on this for a while now. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently support that. However, you can use a native interface and use AWT/Swing to override our default behavior. In AWT you can get the [list of frames in the application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames()) (the app windows) then you need to use [getWindowListeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindowListeners()) to get and remove our builtin listener that exits on close.

Now the window won't close, you can add your own window listener and implement your own hiding logic e.g. `setVisible(false)` in `windowClosed`.